# C# - Is there an interface for math?

Tags: generics, inheritance, c#-3.0

I was working on a matrix-class, in which i want to make som linear algebra functions. I want to have a generic type in the matrix, which you can do arithmetic operations with, since i want to make a class representing a fraction instead of using double, but i also wanna use double in the future. Like this:

```
class Temp<T>
    {
        T[,] matrix;
        // Example of a math-using function
        public T Sum()
        {
            T sum = matrix[0,0];
            for(int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    sum += matrix[i, j]; // Error here
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

I thought that i could use something like `where T : IMathable` but i couldn't figure out what inheirentents it should have.

Comment: [Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/) has been previewed for a while and I believe did make it into the released .NET 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in .NET 7 / C# 11:

```cs
class Temp<T> where T : INumber<T>
{
    T[,] matrix;
    public T Sum()
    {
        T sum = matrix[0, 0];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                sum += matrix[i, j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the documents?

There is a Math class, you can check if that's the one you want [Math Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-7.0)

you import it with

```
using System;
```

Please give me a feedback on that. If this one doesn't solve try to be more specific, mentioning the language that **has** the function you want can help us to help you.

Comment: I want to restrict a generic to only  types that are able to do arithmetic, i can't see how System.Math will help with that

Comment: You can try looking for a library to solve that, else you'll end up doing it manually.

Comment: And Generic Math seams to accomplish it